# How to setup a controller manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to render a view to a string inside a bare-bones class.  I referenced MVC.  I'm looking at this example: https://gist.github.com/eralston/d68287b6634f963c09c7
The problem is, they are assuming this is within the context of an MVC project.  I have to provide the dependencies for `FindPartialView`. I've fiddled around with a bunch of options, here, and can't even get a compileable instance.

Here's one of my attempts.  I even tried creating a controller, but I cant figure out how to set any of the options, and MVC controllers are instantiated by the front controller magically, so I don't know what to actually do to configure the `controllerContext` and `TempData`.  Specifically, what comes to mind is, where can I set my document root?

```
var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary();
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext()
{

};
viewDataDictionary.Model = model;

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, viewDataDictionary, TempData, sw);

}
```

Comment: Is there no reason you cant just add a controller via the solution explorer?

Comment: It's not an MVC project, though I did try to create a Controller, I still couldn't find out how to configure the controller, but, also, I shouldn't need to create a full new controller.  I only need a `ControllerContext`.  I'm assuming that is instantiated magically in a normal MVC application.

Comment: This is just a plain Class Library. I've added one class, and that's the contents. Then I ran `install-package System.Web.Mvc MyProj`

Comment: Don't use MVC for this when you aren't doing MVC.  Just use the Razor templating engine.

Comment: @Amy, How do I do that?  I found this example: https://scottsauber.com/2018/07/07/walkthrough-creating-an-html-email-template-with-razor-and-razor-class-libraries-and-rendering-it-from-a-net-standard-class-library/comment-page-1 but it doesn't say how I generate the dependencies for `RazorViewToStringRenderer` in a .Net Core Library.

Comment: Google ".net core razor template engine" and use the library from Github